# Атака на режим CBC при фиксированном IV

Tags: криптография, режимы-шифрования

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую атаку можно построить для такой задачи.
Есть строка (ее длина не более 5). Строка дополняется до 16 байт нулями, а потом шифруется при помощи CBC. В качестве IV используется текущее время. После шифрования мы можем получить строку: IV+ciphertext. Также есть доступ к оракулу, который шифрует на том же ключе произвольные сообщения. Необходимо расшифровать детерминированно данную строку.

Comment: В итоге речь идет об одном блоке шифротекста? Или несколько блоков? То есть если длина строки не более 5 и padding до 16 - то это 1 блок, тогда причем здесь CBC?

Comment: Когда шифруем строку, у нас только 1 блок в 16 байт

Comment: Могу кинуть ссылку на полное задание. Может, так будет понятней: https://github.com/CryptoCourse/CryptoLabs/blob/master/docs/labCbcFixedIvAttack.md

Comment: Я думала, про атаку BEAST,  но в таком случае нужен перебор.

Comment: проверь, действительно ли «текущее время» — это текущее время, а не просто константа... если это константа, то это просто перебор всех 20к вариантов... если это текущее время, то доступно ли нам время с которым была зашифрована строка?

Comment: @Fat-Zer доступно: нам метод шифрования возвращает это время (оно же IV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я понимаю условие:

- У нас есть блок шифротекста C<sub>0</sub> и вектор инициализации *IV<sub>0</sub>* , который использовался при его шифровании в режиме CBC. И нам известно, что открытый текст P<sub>0</sub> для C<sub>0</sub> состоит из 1—5 ASCII-цифр, дополненных нулями.
- Также у нас есть оракул, который для произвольного открытого текста P<sub>n</sub> возвращает *IV<sub>n</sub>.C<sub>n</sub>* — сообщение, зашифрованное тем же алгоритмом и тем же ключём что и исходный текст. При этом *IV<sub>n</sub>* — это текущее время в секундах, значение, которое мы с высокой долей вероятности можем предугадать.

---

#### Идея атаки:

т.к. при режиме CBC схема шифрования первого блока выглядит как:

- *С<sub>n</sub> = E(IV<sub>n</sub>⊕P<sub>n</sub>)*

то можно в качестве *P<sub>n</sub>* использовать:

- *P<sub>n</sub> = IV<sub>n</sub>⊕P<sub>t</sub>⊕IV<sub>0</sub>*

где P<sub>t</sub> — это искомый открытый текст, тогда

- *С<sub>n</sub> = E(IV<sub>n</sub>⊕IV<sub>n</sub>⊕P<sub>t</sub>⊕IV<sub>0</sub>) = E(IV<sub>0</sub>⊕P<sub>t</sub>)*

И в случае если *С<sub>n</sub> = С<sub>0</sub>*, *P<sub>t</sub>* и будет искомым P<sub>0</sub>.

Т.к. вероятных *P<sub>t</sub>* относительно немного (*111 110*, с учётом более коротких строк) то можно организовать их полный перебор. Очередной IV<sub>n</sub> для формирования P<sub>n</sub> можно предугадать с высокой долей вероятности, запросив текущее время. Само собой, проверять, действительно ли текст был зашифрован с предсказанным вектором инициализации нужно для каждого значения.

Answer (score 1):

По сути речь идет об атаке на 1 блок шифротекста, который путем нехитрых манипуляций превращается в 1 блок (фактически атака на ECB)

Схема атаки шифротекста:

1. `Json -> Base64`
2. `Base64 -> CBC_Byte[16]`
3. `CBC_Byte[] xor IV[16] -> ECB_Byte[16]`

Далее остается только *brute force* со словарем `[0..9]`, длиной 5, на полученный массив байтов. Количество переборов 10^5 =  сто тысяч вариантов. Максимум несколько минут (с учетом сетевых Rest запросов).

Comment: То есть мы по факту передаем оракулу предполагаемое m (получаем перебором) XOR IV. Получаем C. Если C совпало с изначальным шифротекстом, то выиграли?

Comment: Просто не очень понятно в таком случае, почему нельзя просто перебирать m и сравнивать их с результатом validate.